# Swapping variable values without creating a new one

Tags: algorithms, math

Recently, I was faced with a question that asked me to swap variable values without creating an extra variable.

i.e. A = 10, B = 20. How store 20 to A and 10 to B?

The solution is:

```
A = A + B     #new value of A=30
B = B + A     #new value of B=50
A = B - A     #new value of A=20
B = B - 2 * A #new value of B=10
```

so A = 20 and B = 10

Does this algorithm have a known name?

Comment: Why is there subtraction and multiplication going on, can you provide more details? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There are no more details to explain... I posted a algorithm and I'd want to know whether exists a name for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-third-variable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a longer and less efficient variant of [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). I'll just reiterate most-commonly known solutions here from the wiki:

```
# solution 1
A = A + B
B = A - B
A = A - B

# solution 2 (^ is XOR)
A = A ^ B
B = B ^ A
A = A ^ B
```

---

@PEMapModder

> On the second last line, there is no difference between `A^B` and `B^A` right? Why swap them?

There is no difference between them. I think [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) swaps them for historical reasons: For machine instructions that use 2 registers for binary operations (source and target/destination, unlike MIPS which uses 3 registers for binary ops), you would write the XOR solution as follows:

```
XOR A B       # A = A ^ B
XOR B A       # B = B ^ A
XOR A B       # A = A ^ B
```

Comment: What's wrong with `A, B = B, A`? That's how it works in a lot of the languages I am familiar with.

Comment: I think OP was challenged to find a solution to the problem without using parallel assignment. That would've been too easy.

Comment: What "OP" means?

Comment: "Original Poster", ie, you.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the XOR solution should be immune to over-/under-flow, whereas solution 1 and OP's solution *might* be affected.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, because my question was a algorithm issue, not syntax.

Comment: On the second last line, there is no difference between `A^B` and `B^A` right? Why swap them?